# How to Connect my SQL Server 2012 to store and get its database from a storage server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 installed on our Office.

and its storage is going to be full

what I want is that How can I connect my SQL Server to another Server to store its database and files

there.

means I want to have a connection to another Server for just storing my database files.

If I create new database it should also be created in the new server.

the server will not be running any databases it just will be a storage place.

How can I create a connection from my SQL Server to an Storage Server.

what I mean is the second server will be just as a secondary storage for my SQL Server

if my current server gets full than it should automatically stores its data to another server.

please proved with a detailed answer because it is first time i faced this issue.

Comment: Please provide a detailed question, for example what do you mean by a storage server? Do you mean a SAN? A seperate file server? You basically need more logical disks on your SQL Server. You can only add database files to a 'local' disk, not a network disk. Once you add database file to an existing database, you can move data into them

Comment: did you read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343.aspx

Comment: I want a connection from SQL Server to another Server to store database files there

Comment: Have you been to - http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and specifically to - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ and drilling into - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: Connection strings has nothing to do with it. You can only store database files on local drives, not remote drives. You need to add another local drive to your SQL Server, make it available as a logical drive, add add database files (.ndf) to it